# Chrome Extension - Open popup from contentScript file

Tags: google-chrome-extension

**I'm trying to open a popup page from DOM event in content script js file**.

I Tried to send message to background page and in the background listener to use:
chrome.browserAction.openPopup() but apparently it's not the way cause browserAction not defined in that context.

**The extension is for audio streaming**, so while browsing that the audio will keep playing in background.
I managed to make the audio playing work in the simple way: when clicking the extension icon => open's the popup => some event in the popup interact with the  from the background and play's the music.

**I want to make it work in the following way**:

1. Content script will add button to the user web page(any page).
   **done**
2. Clicking this button will open the popup, and from there, same logic.

The issue is that I don't know how to open the popup from the content script.
It's actually to trigger to extension icon click from code.

Any ideas?

Comment: You can't use openPopup in the stable Chrome, it's only for Dev/Canary. You can open a new window with your popup.html via chrome.windows.create.

Comment: Using chrome.windows.create it opens the popup as new chrome window (separate instance). It's possible it will open the popup that get opened in the default extension icon click (which is not separate window)?

Comment: No, it's not possible in the stable version of Chrome.

Comment: Thx for the info